# the size problem during assignment of 3D-matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

There are two Questions.

---1---

I can successfully assign a smaller matrix to a bigger zero-matrix without problem, like this:

```
a = zeros(5,5,2);
b = [1 2 3];
a = b;
```

So I try to load the RawData from file to a 3D-matrix:

```
G = ["/Users/ripfreeworld/Documents/MATLAB/RawData/G01.txt",
    "/Users/ripfreeworld/Documents/MATLAB/RawData/G02.txt",
    "/Users/ripfreeworld/Documents/MATLAB/RawData/G03.txt",
    "/Users/ripfreeworld/Documents/MATLAB/RawData/G04.txt"];
rawdata = zeros(1500,200,4);
for i = 1 : 4
    rawdata(:,:,i) = load(G(i),'ascii');
end
```

It got stuck just at the first iteration, without getting any data from the load-function.

Then I commented the line with zeros(). And the first iteration succeed. What's the difference with the former simple code?

---2---
The second problem is:

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is
>   1440-by-152 and the size of the right side is 1440-by-151.

I found that there was an extra column filled with "0". I deleted this column manually this time, but is there any way to keep the 3d form (cube matrix?) , by automatically filling the columns/rows of the smaller matrix with "0" or throwing away the data in the extra columns/rows of the bigger matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Your first code block is plain wrong. You don't 'assign to a bigger matrix', you **overwrite it**. Check the size of `a` before and after assigning `b` to it: it has changed from `5,5,2` to `1,3`.

Comment: without access to the actual data it's very hard to answer any of your questions. Being more specific and posting example code that everyone can follow would go a long way

Comment: Thank you Adriaan, you're right! It was overwriting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Adriaan, the first question was started from a wrong test by overwriting.
For the second question I found an easy solution which is similar

```
p=zeros(5,10)*1/0;
for i=1:5
    for m=1:10
        if isprime((i-1)*10+m-1)
           p(i,m)=(i-1)*10+m-1;
        end
    end
end
```

> ```
> >> p
>
> p =
>
>    NaN   NaN     2     3   NaN     5   NaN     7   NaN   NaN
>    NaN    11   NaN    13   NaN   NaN   NaN    17   NaN    19
>    NaN   NaN   NaN    23   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    29
>    NaN    31   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    37   NaN   NaN
>    NaN    41   NaN    43   NaN   NaN   NaN    47   NaN   NaN
> ```

Comment: You can initialize `p` with `nan(5,10)`. No need to divide by 0!